# not able to print in red color if condition is no

Tags: bash

Inside of  any of file fname2/3/4  no comes then its should show in red color on  html output.
Please help on this

```
fname1=/tmp/servername_bkp.log;
fname2=/tmp/Master_bkp.log;
fname3=/tmp/Nsr_bkp.log;
fname4=/tmp/Rpc_bkp.log;
fname5=/tmp/backup_bkp.log;
while
read -r -u3 line1;
read -r -u4 line2;
read -r -u5 line3;
read -r -u6 line4;
read -r -u7 line5;
  do
  if [ ${line2} == "no" ]; then
    echo `printf "<tr bgcolor="red"><td>${line1}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
   elif [ ${line3} == "no" ]; then
   echo `printf "<tr bgcolor="red"><td>${line3}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
   elif [ ${line4} == "no" ]; then
   echo `printf "<tr bgcolor="red"><td>${line3}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
   echo `printf "<td>${line2}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
   echo `printf "<td>${line3}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
   echo `printf "<td>${line4}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
  echo `printf "<td>${line5}</td></tr>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
  else
  echo `printf "<tr bgcolor="LimeGreen"><td>${line1}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html; 
  echo `printf "<td>${line2}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
  echo `printf "<td>${line3}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
  echo `printf "<td>${line4}</td>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
  echo `printf "<td>${line5}</td></tr>"` >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;  
  fi
```

please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
echo 'printf "<tr bgcolor="red"><td>${line1}</td>"' >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
```

try

```
echo 'printf "<table><tr bgcolor="red"><td>${line1}</td></table>"' >> /tmp/test_bkp.html;
```

You need to enclose `<td>` and `<tr>` tags inside `<table>` tag

Comment: thanks but if line2 is is yes  and line 3 is no means its should show in red for that shall we use the same if conditions. .

Comment: yes you can use the same approach.let me know if you face any issue when doing so

Comment: tried the same still i m getting in green color seems condition is not getting applied.

Comment: server1 Yes No Yes backupserver  in this codition all showing  green

Comment: Is it `No` or `no`?

Comment: thanks you so much both of u. the script is worked after changing No in condition. thanks for correcting me